# Yii2 - How to create progress bar in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

I yii2, we can create progress bar like this :

```
<?php
echo \yii\bootstrap\Progress::widget([
    'percent' => 0,
    'barOptions' => ['class' => 'progress-bar'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'active progress-striped'],
]);
?>
```

If I have a form that I catch them  in ajax,

```
$js2 = <<<JS
$('body').on('beforeSubmit', 'form#dynamic-form', function () {
  // submit form
  console.log('starting ajax request');

$.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                   $('.progress-bar').css('width', (100 * e.loaded / e.total) + '%').attr( "aria-valuenow", (100 * e.loaded / e.total));
                }
            });
            return xhr;
      }, 
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      data: {id : $('#dynamicmodel-nomor_coil').val()}, // nomor coil digunakan sebagai ID
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function (response, status, xhr) {


      },
      complete: function(response, status, xhr){
           $('.progress-bar').css('width','0%').attr( "aria-valuenow", "0");
           return xhr;
      }
 }).done(function() {
    jQuery('#dynamicmodel-nomor_coil').prop('disabled', false);
});

return false;
})
```

Please see in

```
 $('.progress-bar').css('width', (100 * e.loaded / e.total) + '%').attr( "aria-valuenow", (100 * e.loaded / e.total))
```

It works,

The Problem is when I try to reset them in ajax complete, using:

```
$('.progress-bar').css('width','0%').attr( "aria-valuenow", "0");
```

The progress bar not works.
Please advise

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error. Html code that generated like this : <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div id="w1" class="active progress-striped progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"><span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span></div>
</div>
                            </div>

Comment: So, the progress bar is not show if I reset them.

Comment: Did you try $('.progress-bar').css('width','0').attr( "aria-valuenow", "0");